# get the number of elements currently pending in a stream

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, streamcontroller

If I have a `StreamContoller` and a `StreamSubscription` and I have called `StreamSubscription.pause()` how can I get the count of the elements in currently pending in the stream?

Comment: "how can I get the count [...]" - you cannot

Comment: Before pausing the stream you need to get all elements count then count till the stream is paused.